# Transparent animation in Metal, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, shader, metal

I’m creating animation using Metal. I draw my animation on black MTKView using MTKViewDelegate methods. My purpose is to simulate petrol and make it half-transparent like this:

[Half-transparent animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1R1i.png)

Now it looks like this:

[My current animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ggjsf.jpg)

When I set alpha in my fragment shader, nothing happens, though coloring works fine:

```
    fragment half4 fragment_shader(VertexOut fragData [[stage_in]], float2 pointCoord [[point_coord]]) {
        float dist = length(pointCoord - float2(0.6));
        float4 color = fragData.color;
        // Marking particles round shaped
        color.a = 1.0 - smoothstep(0.4, 0.4, dist);
        // Setting yellow color with 0.5 alpha
        color.b = (0.6, 0.2, 0.7, 0.5);
        return half4(color);     
    }
```

I also have attachmentDescriptor, but it still doesn't make alpha work:

> ```
>          let attachmentDesciptor: MTLRenderPipelineColorAttachmentDescriptor =
>  pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0]
>          attachmentDesciptor.isBlendingEnabled = true
>          attachmentDesciptor.rgbBlendOperation = MTLBlendOperation.add
>          attachmentDesciptor.alphaBlendOperation = MTLBlendOperation.add
>          attachmentDesciptor.sourceRGBBlendFactor = .sourceAlpha
>          attachmentDesciptor.sourceAlphaBlendFactor = .sourceAlpha
>          attachmentDesciptor.destinationRGBBlendFactor = MTLBlendFactor.oneMinusSourceAlpha
>          attachmentDesciptor.destinationAlphaBlendFactor = MTLBlendFactor.oneMinusSourceAlpha
> ```

EDITED:

I've also tried setting `metalView.isOpaque` to `false`, but it only changed background:

[Same animation with different background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUl5m.jpg)

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried setting `opaque` to `NO` on an `MTKView`?

Comment: Yes, it makes background white, but doesn't change animation

Answer (score 0):

Your shader implementation is wrong because your alpha channel is never set to 0.5, in this line:

```
// Setting yellow color with 0.5 alpha
color.b = (0.6, 0.2, 0.7, 0.5);
```

In the line above you're trying to set four dimensional vector to single dimensional component which is wrong.

It's also unclear why you call this function:

```
// Marking particles round shaped
color.a = 1.0 - smoothstep(0.4, 0.4, dist);
```

According to Metal shader language:

> Results are undefined if edge0 >= edge1

In order to achieve the desired result you should replace your shader fragment function with this:

```
fragment half4 fragment_shader(VertexOut fragData [[stage_in]], float2 pointCoord [[point_coord]]) {
        float dist = length(pointCoord - float2(0.6));
        float4 color = fragData.color;
        // Marking particles round shaped
        // color.a = 1.0 - smoothstep(0.4, 0.4, dist);
        // Setting yellow color with 0.5 alpha
        // color.b = (0.6, 0.2, 0.7, 0.5);
        
        // Setting yellow color with 0.5 alpha
        color = (1, 1, 0, 0.5);
        return half4(color);     
    }
```

Comment: I used color.a to make particles round-shaped, not square. Thanks for your reply, your fragment shader works, but it makes particles square and gray. And when I change your color parameters to make particles yellow, it makes them either white or gray again.